# Run ansible using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins

I created a job in jenkins and I want to build the project using ansible. I want to run my command on several host (that's why I use ansible). When I try to run the project it fails with some permission error:

```
/home/ubuntu/install.sh -s -U ubuntu -f 5
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/ansible" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Standard Demo/workspace"): error=13, Permission denied
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
  at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
  at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
```

Do you know what the problem is? I am logged into the jenkins server as admin user.

Comment: Your jenkins jobs run as user `jenkins`, who by default does not have a shell which ansible would require. Try that route first.

Comment: can you take the snapshoot of your jenkins job and share, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Ansible problem, it is a configuration issue in Jenkins. As others have noted, by default Jenkins will run as a "normal user" (typically `jenkins`). That is the user that jobs and steps (including shell scripts like the one you're calling) will run as. In your case, this user does not have sufficient permissions to run Ansible.

I don't recommend changing this default user because a. there are good security reasons for this setup, and b. it can actually be complex to do right, because you would have to address permissions issues for all of Jenkins to match the new user. However, it's quite easy to do things like run `sudo` from within a Script build step. Just use that tool (and a properly configured `/etc/sudoers`) to gain the permissions you need during the build.